# Eviction of data from Kafka key value state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, key-value-store, kafka-topic

I am performing aggregation using kafkaStreams which actually keeps all my aggregated records into a keyValue state store against a specific key which i am generating to uniquely identify that aggregation.
I am not using any kafka window for this aggregation.
so essentially this method will keep of listening to input data and thus keep on aggregating.
Now based on the key, i need to apply different logic to search from the stateStore and move my data downstream.

Kafka's KeyValueStateStore gives me 4 methods viz, all, prefixScan, range and get.
Of which based on the key i am generating, i find i can only use all and get.

1. if i use get, kafka will internally scan over the complete statestore and give me data for the specific key, so if i have a list of keys, it will iterate over complete statestore for the number of keys in the list.
2. If I manage to create a regex for my search key, i can use all() and iterate over all data in statestore in a java logic and search for my regex and move downstream.
   but again it will be a manual iteration over the complete statestore.

P.S. at any point in time my statestore will contain at least a billion records.

Can someone please suggest the best (performance wise) possible way to retrieve data using a key search into kafka keyValue stateStore.
or any alternative to the approach is appreciated.

Update:
After eviction of data from statestore, i am not deleting it but wish to update it with a flag stating evicted or not.
Which can only be possible by having a read/write access to the statestore which is again only available through pipeline as interactive queries give only a read access to the statestore. This is what my knowledge of Kafka limits to. Please help if otherwise.

Comment: It's a KV-store... `get` should be an O(1) operation, and not scan over the entire store. If you really want something more performant, then I feel like using a proper database server with indicies would help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Apache Spark streaming to use this

1. Read data from Kafka through spark streaming
2. Perform aggregations/transformations in spark
3. Push the sanitized data into desired downstream topics

I am not sure if this can be done in Kafka

Comment: Yes, Kafka Streams can do this. Spark's own aggregate state operations dont really solve the question that was asked.